# Image Slideshow not fading out then fading in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a image slideshow that chooses a random image, fades out the current image, and fades in the randomly selected image. If that makes sense. If not, the code might explain what I'm trying to do:

```
function cycleImages(){
  var images = [
      "gallery-1.jpg",
      "gallery-2.jpg",
      "gallery-3.jpg"

  ];
  var randomImg = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]
  $("#switch").attr("src",randomImg).fadeOut(4000).stop(true,true).hide().fadeIn(4000)
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval('cycleImages()', 7000);
})
```

This is my first time using Jquery. I want it to fade out before it selects a randomly selected image, but it simply disappears with a hard transition and fades in the next image. Please help me out, thank you!

Comment: If i'm understanding your code correctly you are using the `attr` to replace the `src` image, this wont transition because you are simply overwriting the `src` therefore the DOM doesn't know to transition instead it just loads the new `src` image.

Comment: @AaronMcGuireis there any way to make it fade out though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fadeOut takes a second parameter. A callback function when fading out is complete.
Something like this:

```
$("#switch").attr("src",randomImg).fadeOut(4000, () => {
    //this will run after fading out.
    $("#switch").fadeIn(4000);
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/17w3edgv/1/